# Google Recaptcha only appearing about 3/4 of the time

Tags: jquery, captcha, recaptcha

I am trying to implement Google's new Recapthca (no captcha?) on my site.

I have the link to the API in my `<head>` and am calling the captcha in form as such:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="KEY" style="transform:scale(0.70)"></div>
```

The only modification I've made is changing the scale.

The problem is the Captcha only appears about 3/4 of the time. I am at a loss as to why.

This form is in a div that is initially set to `display:none` and uses jquery to appear when another element is hovered over. Could this have something to do with it?

Link for those interested: http://heretohelphomecare.com.au/index.php?id=6 (Scroll to bottom of page and hover over the light brown area)

Comment: `Could this have something to do with it?` I guess it could be, ya. But not sure then why 3/4 of the time it works. But seems not too hard to test it and see what's going on

Comment: hey @MeltingDog, do you have a link to share to take a look, or could you post jsfiddle maybe?

Comment: @oserk yep - have added above